PlayerView has a black screen
I'm building a video player using ExoPlayer. Sometimes, the PlayerView has a black screen when I finish the activity and re-open it. If I press the play/pause button, the PlayerView stays black but if I press the seek to next/previous 5s button then the video is played. But I want to play the video when it's ready and hide the controller.
Here is my activity:
class PreviewActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityPreviewBinding, ActivityPreviewViewModel>() {
    override fun getViewBinding(): ActivityPreviewBinding =
        ActivityPreviewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    override fun getViewModelClass(): Class<ActivityPreviewViewModel> =
        ActivityPreviewViewModel::class.java

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    override fun setupListener() {
        binding.apply {
            vv.player?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
                override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "[onIsPlayingChanged] IsPlaying: $isPlaying")
                    if (!isPlaying) {
                        vv.player?.play()
                    }
                }

                override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                    super.onPlayerError(error)
                    Log.e(TAG, "[onPlayerError] Error: ${error.message}", error)
                }

                override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                    super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                    Log.d(TAG, "[onPlaybackStateChanged] PlaybackState: $playbackState")
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun setupViews() {
        val bundle = intent.extras
        val videoPath = bundle?.getString(BUNDLE_VIDEO_PATH)
        setupVideo(videoPath)
    }

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    private fun setupVideo(videoPath: String?) {
        try {
            binding.vv.apply {
                val uri = Uri.parse(videoPath)
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
                val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this@PreviewActivity).build()
                exoPlayer.repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                exoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
                exoPlayer.addAnalyticsListener(EventLogger())
                useController = false
                resizeMode = RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding.vv.player?.clearMediaItems()
        binding.vv.player?.clearVideoSurface()
        binding.vv.player?.release()
    }

    companion object {
        const val BUNDLE_VIDEO_PATH = "videoPath"
        private const val ONE_SECOND = 1000L
        private const val TAG = "PreviewActivity"
    }
}

Both setupListener() and setupViews() are called at onCreate() func.
When I was trying to log the states of the Player, I realize that if video is played, the playbackState is changed to 3 which is STATE_READY and isPlaying == true. But if the screen is black, the playbackState is changed to 2 which is STATE_BUFFERING after STATE_READY and isPlaying == false without any exception.
2024-10-11 15:46:30.799 PreviewActivity         D  [onPlaybackStateChanged] PlaybackState: 3
2024-10-11 15:46:30.800 PreviewActivity         D  [onIsPlayingChanged] IsPlaying: true
2024-10-11 15:46:30.817 ViewRootIm...wActivity] I  MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2024-10-11 15:46:35.707 PreviewActivity         D  [onPlaybackStateChanged] PlaybackState: 2
2024-10-11 15:46:35.708 PreviewActivity         D  [onIsPlayingChanged] IsPlaying: false

So I try to vv.player?.play() when isPlaying == false but it's not working .

Just like it said, it's buffering, loading stream data from the source.

@Kolyneh It was buffering all day non-stop but didn't played the video yet.

Oh that's weird. Have your try the ExoPlayer demo to load your video? Quite simple in it's PlayerActivity, you can check to see if you’re missing some steps.

It is just sometimes, and if I press the Skip forward/rewind 5 seconds btn, the video will play. @Kolyneh

Then, try the ExoPlayer demo with your video url. In ExoPlayer project's ./demos/main/src/main/assets/media.exolist.json file, find the "Progressive" node, add your video url to "samples" list and name it, then launch the demo app then select your video to play.

I added the video settings code to binding.vv.post{} and it solved my problem.
